# How to search a job for multiple days using monitor work load in TWS Workload Scheduler?

Tags: scheduler, tws, workload

Please help me to understand how to search a job or stream for multiple days using workload scheduler, i tried to use "Time Data Filter" but it is not working as expected.

The "List plan" allows to select any one archived dates. i tired symnew, but no joy. It allows only to search for a particular date.

I would like to search a job for X days and get the Start/End time as an output.
For example: I need to search a job "XXXX" from 1st march till 30th March.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search day by day using archived plans.

To look to jobs at any date, you can use a "Job Run History Report", this will include only a subset of the information, but allows to find jobs on larger date intervals.

History is kept in the database and you can alternatively run queries using SQL.

The history is automatically cleanup up after some days specified by logHistory / lh optman option, that by default is set to 400 days.

Comment: Thankyou Franco. That reallly helped.
I tried the same, and found that the reporting was not enabled in my engine. Further I found that it can be enabled through "Mange Engines" >> "Database configuration for Reporting".
But i believe the Datbase user ID and Pasword will be available only for the Administrators. Is there is a way, the admin can assign the access to a role and allocate the role to some operators ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the product documentation there is information on how to grant access to reporting views to an additional db user to be used for reporting.
Consider also to use batch reports in order to schedule the reports you need.